# Conflicting types (Functions)

Tags: c

I have two .c files, `main.c` and `test.c` 
And two header files, `type.h` and `interface.h`

Where interface.h includes type.h

`test.c` includes the headerfile `"interface.h"`

```
#include "interface.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int create(Ptr * p) {
//do stuff

}

int addToFront(Ptr * p, void * T) {
//do stuff later
}
```

`main.c` also includes `"interface.h"`

```
#include "interface.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

and has a function which I want to call In `test.c`

```
void isEqual(void * L, void * Item) {

}
```

How would I call the function isEqual in test.c?

because doing this in test.c:

`isEqual(p,T);` `//in the addToFront function,`

specifics a implicit declaration/ conflicting types error. I'm not allowed to put these functions into test.c, so I'm forced to call them like this, would a include guard possible solve this issue?

Comment: basically you want isEqual (in test.c) can be called from main.c?
if so, you could declare isEqual prototype in any header that being included by main.c

Comment: If `isEqual` is defined in `main.c` and you want to call it in `test.c`, you should put the function prototype in `interface.h`. OT: as a general rule, you should include the standard headers *before* including your own headers.

Comment: I've added a prototype of isEqual in main.c, but I still get an implicit declaration error, when calling it from test.c. I don't think I'm allowed to modify the header files(For this project), is their any other way of doing this?

Comment: The prototype of `isEqual` needs to be available in `test.c`, because you're calling the function in `test.c`. If the prototype is not in `interface.h` and you aren't allowed to change `interface.h`, then you need to a) create your own header file with the prototype, b) include that header in both `main.c` and `test.c`.

Comment: something seems really strange in your setup: you said that interface.h is read only file (you can't modify). As you said, interface.h includes test.h, which let me think that test.h is given with interface.h and thus must be read only,  as well. But if test.h is readonly, test.c will probably be readonly as well... but then, how can it use a function that is in main???
can you give more info about the contraints and what you are really expect to do?

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of `isEqual` needs to be available in `test.c`, because you're calling the function in `test.c`. If the prototype is not in `interface.h` and you aren't allowed to change `interface.h`, then you need to a) create your own header file with the prototype, b) include that header in both `main.c` and `test.c`. – user3386109

Answer (score 0):

You speak of a *conflicting types error*. This suggests that `test.c` is not *linked* to, but *included* in `main.c` before the definition of `isEqual`. Under those circumstances you could just put the prototype

```
void isEqual(void *L, void *Item);
```

early in `test.c`.

p. s.: It is rather strange for a function named `isEqual` to have `void` return type.